# how can test u=g.user in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate, flask-testing

Lets say I have flask Application Now I want to test u=g.user.be_friend(user) which make a user friend with eachother if they werene't friend befor But I don't know how I can test g.user and most importantly g.user.be_friend would you please help thanx ?

view.py:

```
    user = Users.query.filter_by(name = name).first()
    if user is None:
        flash('User %s not found.' % name)
        return redirect(url_for('layout.user'))
    if user == g.user:
        flash('You can\'t Friend yourself!')
        return redirect(url_for('layout.user',page=1, sortby='normal'))
    u = g.user.be_friend(user)
```

mytest_app.py:

```
def test_friend_main(self):
        e1 = Users(name='admine1', email='admine2@gmail.com', age=25)
        e2 = Users(name='teste2', email='teste2@gmail.com', age=27)
        db.session.add_all([e1, e2])
        db.session.commit()
        with self.client:
            self.assertTrue(g.user =='admine1')

        e1.be_friend(e2)
        response=self.client.get('/friend/admine1', follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertTrue('You are now Friend with !',response.data)
```

Comment: Do you have a test db?

Comment: Yes I have @Jimilian I create my_test.sqlite

Comment: When I don't see any problem. You should register two users. Login using one of them -> g.user is current logged in user. And make a post request to execute `be_friend` method. After that you should check `are_friends`. Be carefully, you should use new users or new database each test.

Comment: this is the thing that I come up with But will  get error self.assertTrue(g.user =='admine1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'
and if I dont use g.user get error    u = g.user.be_friend(user)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'be_friend'
@Jimilian any help?

Comment: are you using flask-testing?

Comment: yes I use flask-tetsting
 @Jimilian

Comment: I don't see a `db.session.commit()` for the `be_friend()` call in your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `flask-login` module.

```
from flask.ext.login import current_user

@lm.user_loader   # you should have same function
def load_user(user_id):
   return User.get_user(user_id)

@flask_app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user # save current user in request context.
```

Sadly, but I didn't find any easy way to get current `g` value in test code. Only hard way with [test_request_context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/). Anyway, you can test `current_user`, if it passed to template:

```
def test_something(self)
     self.assertEqual(self.get_context_variable('current_user').name, name_should_be)
```

But at first, you should login:

```
response = self.client.post('/login', data=dict(name='admine1', email='admine2@gmail.com'))
```

`User` model can be improved: `class User(UserMixin, db.Model):`

Also, in test you shouldn't execute `e1.be_friend(e2)` directly. You should execute it from your production code.

Comment: thanx would u please tell me how should it be in code which part I should change in my testcode @Jimilian

Comment: get this error   self.assertEqual(g.user.name, 'admine1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user' @Jimilian

Comment: @LiLi, I had updated my answer. I found a new mistake in your code - your `Users` model is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer/ which part is wrong @Jimilian ??

Comment: @LiLi, I removed part about `Users` model, because this fix doesn't help you :( There is no easy way to test `g` variable. Because it state leaves only in request time. It's empty before and it's empty after. But you can test everything you put in template using `get_context_variable`.

Comment: thanx so Much  @ Jimilian it doesnt still fix the error But I put it as a best answer Coz it gives a good Idea and hopefull I can make it work ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a unit test for the "followers" feature of the [Flasky](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky) application that I feature in my book. Here is the test, you can probably take some ideas from it:

```
def test_follows(self):
    u1 = User(email='john@example.com', password='cat')
    u2 = User(email='susan@example.org', password='dog')
    db.session.add(u1)
    db.session.add(u2)
    db.session.commit()
    self.assertFalse(u1.is_following(u2))
    self.assertFalse(u1.is_followed_by(u2))
    timestamp_before = datetime.utcnow()
    u1.follow(u2)
    db.session.add(u1)
    db.session.commit()
    timestamp_after = datetime.utcnow()
    self.assertTrue(u1.is_following(u2))
    self.assertFalse(u1.is_followed_by(u2))
    self.assertTrue(u2.is_followed_by(u1))
    self.assertTrue(u1.followed.count() == 2)
    self.assertTrue(u2.followers.count() == 2)
    f = u1.followed.all()[-1]
    self.assertTrue(f.followed == u2)
    self.assertTrue(timestamp_before <= f.timestamp <= timestamp_after)
    f = u2.followers.all()[-1]
    self.assertTrue(f.follower == u1)
    u1.unfollow(u2)
    db.session.add(u1)
    db.session.commit()
    self.assertTrue(u1.followed.count() == 1)
    self.assertTrue(u2.followers.count() == 1)
    self.assertTrue(Follow.query.count() == 2)
    u2.follow(u1)
    db.session.add(u1)
    db.session.add(u2)
    db.session.commit()
    db.session.delete(u2)
    db.session.commit()
    self.assertTrue(Follow.query.count() == 1)
```

When you look at this code, keep in mind that this application makes users followers of themselves, so for example, the follower count when a user just follows another user is two, not one.